# Solr: Filtering on the number of matches in an OR query to a multivalued field

Tags: solr

Given the following example solr documents:

```
<doc>
  <field name="guid">1</field>
  <field name="name">Harry Potter</field>
  <field name="friends">ron</field>
  <field name="friends">hermione</field>
  <field name="friends">ginny</field>
  <field name="friends">dumbledore</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="guid">2</field>
  <field name="name">Ron Weasley</field>
  <field name="friends">harry</field>
  <field name="friends">hermione</field>
  <field name="friends">lavender</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="guid">3</field>
  <field name="name">Hermione Granger</field>
  <field name="friends">harry</field>
  <field name="friends">ron</field>
  <field name="friends">ginny</field>
  <field name="friends">dumbledore</field>
</doc>
```

and the following query (or filter query):

```
friends:ron OR friends:hermione OR friends:ginny OR friends:dumbledore
```

all three documents will be returned since they each have at least one of the specified friends.

However, I'd like to set a minimum (and maximum) threshold for how many friends are matched. For example, only return documents that have at least 2 but no more than 3 of the specified friends.

Such a query would only return the third document (Hermione Granger) as she has 3 of the 4 friends specified, while the first (Harry Potter) matches all 4 and the second (Ron Weasley) matches only 1.

Is this possible in a Solr query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to use a [function query](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Function+Queries), `termfreq`, and count the number of terms (aka "friends" in your case) matched. You can sum up the results, then only return documents within your threshold, using `frange`, like this:

```
{!frange l=2 u=3}sum(termfreq(friends,'ron'),termfreq(friends,'hermione'),termfreq(friends,'ginny'),termfreq(friends,'dumbledore'))
```

`termfreq(...)` will return `1` for each friend found, and the sum of those is what you test against your threshold (the lower and upper bounds you specified in the beginning of your `!frange` statement).

You can place this in the `q:` field or `fq:` field. Here it is in the Solr admin panel for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Do you know a way to use wildcards in the `termfreq` fq? so you could use `termfreq(text, manage*)` to match "Manager", "Manage" and "Management"?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way I can see is just adding a 'nbOfFriends' field and populate it in the source or in a UpdateProcessor.

If you don't want to add this additional field, you might look at [Joins](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join), but I am not sure if it allows you to query number of children in a join, you should check.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it's not as easy as a total friends count. I need the count of friends matching those specified in the query, which will be dynamic. Also, I'm not seeing immediately how joins could help.