# Mixing Solr range function with additional parameters

Tags: java, solr

I have a range function in a Solr `fq` that works as expected:

```
{!frange l=1 u=2}sum(termfreq(tags,'twitter'),termfreq(tags,'facebook'),termfreq(tags,'pinterest'))
```

However, if I try to further refine it by adding an additional parameter to the end:

```
{!frange l=1 u=2}sum(termfreq(tags,'twitter'),termfreq(tags,'facebook'),termfreq(tags,'pinterest')) AND (region:"US")
```

I get the error: **org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Unexpected text after function: AND (region:"US")**

If I try to prepend an additional parameter:

```
(region:"US") AND {!frange l=1 u=2}sum(termfreq(tags,'twitter'),termfreq(tags,'facebook'),termfreq(tags,'pinterest'))
```

I get the error: **org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Expected ')' at position 27 in 'sum(termfreq(tags,'twitter''**

I've tried wrapping the range portion in additional parenthesis but still having no luck. How can I combine a range function with additional query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got solved what I need to. Basically, I was running commands from the Solr admin dashboard. Although I wasn't able to mix the `frange` command above with other queries in `fq`, I was able to put my `frange` command in `q` and keep the other queries in `fq`.

```
q: {!frange l=1 u=2}sum(termfreq(tags,'twitter'),termfreq(tags,'facebook'),termfreq(tags,'pinterest'))

fq: (region:"US")
```

I answered a [similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488883/solr-filtering-on-the-number-of-matches-in-an-or-query-to-a-multivalued-field/16548210#16548210)

My issue is solved, but I'll leave this unanswered for a few days in case someone knows of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer here: [Nested functional range query with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516945/nested-functional-range-query-with-or/47176816#47176816)

which solves this problem using *query* solr feature.

Answer (score -1):

You can also keep adding `fq=` parameters this is seen as an AND, for example:

```
&fq={!frange l=1 u=2}sum(termfreq(tags,'twitter'),termfreq(tags,'facebook'),termfreq(tags,'pinterest'))&fq=region:"US"
```