# Nested functional range query with OR

Tags: solr

I'm trying to do a functional query with an OR/AND however it seems there are limitations in doing so. Here is the logic for the SQL equivalent of the query I'm trying to perform:

```
ABS(col1-:val1)<1 OR (col1 IS NULL AND ABS(col2-:val1)<1)
```

Here is my current working fq query to grab the the documents with an ABS difference of <1.

```
fq={!frange l=0 u=1}abs(sub(col1,val1))
```

Here is what I'm trying to execute but can't without error

```
fq={!frange l=0 u=1}abs(sub(col1,val1)) OR (-col1:[* TO *] AND {!frange l=0 u=1}abs(sub(col2,val1)))
```

It seems like it's not possible to use and AND or and OR in the same fq when using a functional query. How would I go about doing this? I am using solr 4.1. Thanks

Comment: Check if (-col1:[* TO *] AND {!frange l=0 u=1}abs(sub(col2,val1)) works first. Have seen some issues with -col1:[* TO *] you can try (*:* -col1:[* TO *])

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that still throws an error. This guy had the same problem. His solution was to separate the queries. That works fine if you're going to intersect everything, but it won't work for OR.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545115/mixing-solr-range-function-with-additional-parameters?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fq={!frange l=0 u=1 v=$myabs}&myabs=abs(sub(col1,val1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon similar issue and found out the solution. Posting it here so it might help somebody.
The original query can be modified like this using *query*:"..." feature of solr:

```
fq=_query_:"{!frange l=0 u=1}abs(sub(col1,val1))" OR (-col1:[* TO *] AND _query_:"{!frange l=0 u=1}abs(sub(col2,val1)))"
```